# How to finish called activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

This code starts a new `Activity`.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

How can I close/finish this activity (which I just started with the code above)?

Comment: check `android:launchMode` "singleTask" and "singleInstance" [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) . youc can try this `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` too in your manifest, and it will die when its done or a new task is being created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  Once that activity is started, you'll be on the back stack until it finishes (or the user navigates back via recents or launcher icons if thats another app).  The other activity needs to finish itself to let you come back.

Answer (score 3):

**What you are doing:**
You are starting `Activity-B` from `Activity-A`

**What happens during this mechanism:**

- When first of all `Activity-A` is started it kinda goes to
  [backstack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)
- When you say start `Activity-B` kinda goes to [backstack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) on top `Activity-A`.
- So now if you call `finish();` in in `Activity-A` it cannot close since
  it is in [backstack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) so it will result in a different response like
  restarting the same activity again or something else

---

**So summerizing my point**: As [Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan) in one of answers suggested .... you have to close `Activity-B` and then `Activity-A`.